# From my web server, how to run a script in the graphical environment?

Tags: apache2, skype, xvfb

I have a web app that is meant to connect to Skype. Skype used to have a half-decent API but no more but now there are only a handful of CLI commands that one can run.

I found [some](https://github.com/shokai/skype-ruby) [wrappers](https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py) that worked when sending messages in the shell. Alas, Skype must be running in the same environment as the web server.

I've been trying to use xvfb to run a "headless" instance of skype before sending a message to it. I tried to use the `--secondary` and `--pipelogin` options. I tried to run skype as root or to run xvfb as root.

The only way these scripts work is if I run them in a terminal in the same environment where my skype is logged in, but I the the www-data user to run it. Any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to do the same, I ended up using [Sevabot](http://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/). We setup the remote server like this page says. The tricky part is to get the conversation IDs. We did that by `grep`ing the HTML page that sevabot provides which contains all contacts and respective conversation IDs. Because www-data is not an ordinary user, we also created another user with the sole purpose of running skype with xvfb. I believe the server doesn't allow two instances of Skype working, but I can't confirm this.